# How can I exclude external libraries in Rubymine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Rubymine is taking over an hour to index a new project because it is including every Ruby file found on my computer as external libraries.

I do not want any of these files included in my project, but I cannot figure out how to exclude them. If I right click on them, I have the option to delete them, but it actually deletes the file instead of just removing it from the library and I don't want that. I have looked all through the settings and seen nothing about setting the external libraries. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you chose an incorrect project root. I would add an image of your project structure (Preferences → Project: whatever → Project Structure) to the question.

Comment: There is no structure.  It is a completely blank project.  When I click on Project Stucture it says "Nothing to show in the Project Stucture".  Going into the settings for the project it simply shows the name of the folder where the project exists and the ".idea" folder with no contents.

Comment: Your Project pane, then?

Comment: Hmm, are all those files on your ruby load path? How did you install Ruby? What's your OS? Is using Bundler an option?

Comment: @Raffael Ah! They were in my ruby load path.  I removed them from the load path and tried to start a new project but it was still including them, likely because Rubymine isn't looking at the load path after the initial install.  However, that led me to know where it came from.  I was able to remove the external libraries by simply renaming the directories.  A less than satisfying solution, bu it will work.  Thanks.